# What is the difference between a PHP interpreter and a PHP handler?

Tags: web-hosting, php, apache, cpanel, webserver

I'm new to Apache and PHP and I'm currently learning about the interaction between the two.

I am currently trying to understand the job of PHP handlers, I'm using suPHP on cPanel and want to expand on my knowledge.

Comment: Why was this question migrated to SO?

Answer (score 6):

A PHP Handler is an Apache module that is used by Apache to communicate with the PHP Interpreter. It is basically used by Apache to handle requests for PHP files. There are different types of PHP Handlers. For example mod_php is an Apache module for PHP. mod_fcgid allows communication with the php_fpm interpreter over a TCP or Unix socket.

The PHP Interpreter is an application that executes PHP code one line at a time. The output of the PHP Interpreter is sent to the PHP Handler. This output may be processed by other Apache modules such as mod_deflate or mod_security. The final output is sent out of the TCP socket that Apache listens on.

SuPHP is an Apache module that allows executing PHP scripts with the permissions of the script owner. Normally PHP scripts are executed with the permissions of the PHP interpreter. SuPHP allows the PHP files to have custom owner and permissions. The PHP file is then executed by the same owner that owns the PHP file. Its useful in shared hosting environments where PHP files belonging to different users need to be executed by the same PHP interpreter. SuPHP allows the PHP interpreter to execute PHP files with the same permissions as the PHP file.